# Can't resize SpriteKit game properly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

So here's my problem. I am currently trying to create a rectangular enclosure using four more rectangles as borders. So it would look somewhat like this. Keep in mind each side is individual so a rectangle with a border wouldn't work.

[image]

Now the actual problem comes with different screen sizes. Specifically the 4s. Since the screen is *shorter* than other phones, how would I resize the rectangles on the side to fit the height? One of my options was detect the screen size, and then set the height of the rectangle, but I was wondering if there was an easier way since I'd also have to deal with all the other screens.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardcoding, you can get the maximum screen size with `CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)`, similarly there are `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMinX`. With these three methods, you can set proportional height/width and coordinates for the rectangles.

Comment: So I would be getting the screen size with `CGRectGetMaxX `? Why not just use `bounds.width` for example?

Comment: @DIllionDaniels You can use both if they returning the same width/height. And in your case, I think they are the same. The difference between `bounds` and `frame` is they use the difference coordinate system. Read their descriptions. Tell me if you have any problem.